# Django: os.environ.get vs import settings

Tags: django

In a `views.py` would you rather do:

```
from django.conf import settings 
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
```

or

```
import os
stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Thank you for your help. In my settings I am also using the `os.environ.get` import.

Comment: The first approach is better since you're still using the `os.environ` in settings.

Comment: Thank you @Lemayzeur. Would you recommend defining/retrieving all KEYs in the settings and import them from settings. E.g. same case for AWS etc.

Comment: Definitely! this is the best approach.

Comment: Okay perfect, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Settings should only ever change once when the server is started.

If someone were to change your environment whilst still running, then you'd open yourself up to bugs or worse.

---

When it comes to testing, the second approach would lock you in to an extra requirement of needing to be run in an environment where you have full environment controls, rather than being able to switch the settings file thats being used.

---

First approach is DRYer, you already state you are setting this in the settings file anyway so theres no need to set the same value to two variables.

---

tl;dr - Never use the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little off. The first option is how you would access the key in your code but does not specify how the key is gotten. What would do is put

```
import os
stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY').
```

in your settings. You would do this for a couple a reasons, First of all you can but your project on github without anyone seeing your secret key and two if anyone who wasn't supposed to have access to your code does get a hold of it they do not have that information. Basically it is far safer to get the secret key or any key for that matter out of the environment instead of having at in your settings.Then you use option one to access it in the code where it is needed/.

Comment: The op specifies " In my settings I am also using the os.environ.get import."